# Is it legal to hide a recording device in a public place to collect evidence if an item is stolen?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, theft, surveillance

Is it legal to hide an inexpensive smartphone or other recording device in a public place in order to obtain evidence if an item such as a bicycle is stolen?

Comment: Why don't you put a tracker on it? It is certainy better at getting your bike back, than a grainy video of "someone, probably male, in jeans" taking it. And it only tracks your own data.

Comment: Wouldn’t people just steal the camera? Camouflage can’t cover the lens.

Comment: Hello! As your question was originally written, it could be interpreted as a request for legal advice. To avoid having it closed, I rewrote it to be more general. Feel free to edit again if there's anything important that I missed.

Comment: @nvoigt I had done that before. I called the police, while looking on the map on my computer, at where the tracker is. I could tell the police operator exactly where the bike was, as in the exact house. The police refused to do anything, saying "they can't go by trackers."

Comment: @SegNerd They wouldn't expect there to be a camera and so wouldn't think to look for it. Also, by "camera" I actually mean something like an Android phone, so will have many ways of being tracked itself.

Comment: @Someone you really edited the hell out of my questions and now people are slightly misunderstanding it. But yeah I understand about the legal advice thing. Thank you.